# Game Elf 412-in-1

Tags: linux, terminal

(For starters, a Game Elf is a JAMMA board, that plays miniCade game, just so you know)

I've copied my Game Elf SD card over to a new SD card, and have fused to bootloader, so the copied card works on the board. I'm now trying to create a new partition with read/write to save the High Scores to. I've been trying to follow [this tutorial](http://dan.van.derveer.com/twenty/category/arcade/). The problem is, I'm not really that fluent in Linux, as my normal setup is Windows. I've got to step 4, but can't get this command to work: "mkfs.ext2 /dev/"

Here's what [my Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zv1Qk.jpg) looks like.

What I might be entering in wrong?

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself and format it as code with the `{}` icon in the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the modified partition table and exit from `fdisk` (by using the `w` command in `fdisk`) and return to the shell before you can run `mkfs.ext2` or any other program.

Note that formatting a block device requires root privileges so you'll need to use `sudo` with it too, i.e.

```
sudo mkfs.ext2 /dev/sdb4
```